# Peoplesoft pass in array of strings as parameter

Tags: peoplesoft

I'd like to ask how to pass an array of strings as parameter in Peoplesoft.

In Oracle query, I can do that like the following

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME
from   EMPLOYEE
where  EMP_ID in (select regexp_substr(:empid,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual connect by regexp_substr(:empid, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

And pass in parameter value as

```
E001,E002,E003,...
```

But in Peoplesoft Query Manager, when I create the `in` criteria to a subquery, it does not allow `from` clause in it.

Another alternative that I try is using `Prompt` and then pass the value to it, so the query becomes like:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME
from   EMPLOYEE
where  EMP_ID in (:1)
```

But this also does not work.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you are asking about doing this in ps query manager or in peoplecode.
Maybe use older methods, like populating a table first, and joining to that table.  Maybe use a "With" clause.
Please share what you ended up using, to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I'm trying to do with PS Query Manager. It seems it cannot be done. I tried using a prompt so it looks like `where EMP_ID IN (:1)`, but it does not work. My alternative now is that I create 2 sets of queries. One is selecting without passing the parameter (which returns the whole set), and another one is to filter by a specific string (one record per call). I cannot populate a table first as I do not have the sufficient right for that.